# How to list the features of a ZFS pool?

Tags: pool, zfs

How can I list the features of a pool?
With `zfs get all <pool>` I can see the list of properties and their values of a pool. But not the features: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/7/zpool-features.7.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google brought me to your question because I was wondering the same thing... except when I `get all`, I see both options and features.

Feature syntax has appears to have a `feature@<featurename>` appearance. All of my test pool's features were listed after the options, at the bottom of the wall of text that `zpool get all` generated.

Answer (score 1):

To get the pool features, use `zpool get all` not `zfs get all`